# docker compose project name strips underscores, dots and more

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

I googled a bit on this, and managed to find some issues in github but no solution.

My compose file is:

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  mariadb:
    ...
    
  redis:
    ...
```

When I run

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml -p name_1.0
```

and then **docker ps**, the container names are:

- name10_mariadb_1
- name10_redis_1

I also think there is a length limit on the name, and from some length it trims the name.

Is there a workaround for this?
I'd like to be able to have some punctuation in the containers name, specifically dots and underscores.

Answer (score 1):

The default naming convention of docker-compose is `<project>_<service>_<index>[_<slug>]`.
There is no configuration parameter, but since `docker-compose` is `pyhton` project, you can try some hacking.

The function that is generating the name is called `build_container_name` defined in [service.py](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/d0b7bc3110a0794066605670ac4c760c099bab69/compose/service.py).

```py
...
...
def build_container_name(project, service, number, slug=None):
    bits = [project.lstrip('-_'), service]
    if slug:
        bits.extend(['run', truncate_id(slug)])
    else:
        bits.append(str(number))
    return '_'.join(bits)
...
...
```